# Can I see a rollout in more detail?

Tags: kubernetes

I was doing a practice exam on the website killer.sh , and ran into a question I feel I did a hacky solution to. Given a deployment that has had a bad rollout, revert to the ***last*** revision that didn't have any issues. If I check a deployment's rollout history, for example with the command:

```
kubectl rollout history deployment mydep
```

I get a small table with version numbers, and "change-cause" commands. Is there any way to check the changes made to the deployment's yaml file for a specific revision? Because I was stumped in figuring out which specific revision didn't have the error inside of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Behind the scenes a `Deployment` creates a `ReplicaSet` that has its `metadata.generation` set to the `REVISION` you see in `kubectl rollout history deployment mydep`, so you can look at and diff old `ReplicaSet`s associated with the `Deployment`.

On the other hand, being an eventually-consistent system, kubernetes has no notion of "good" or "bad" state, so it can't know what was the last successful deployment, for example; that's why deployment tools like `helm`, `kapp` etc. exist.

Comment: Yes, this was the answer I needed. I didn't realize Kubernetes stores the old replica sets for previous revisions. You can check those manually and find the one without errors. I agree with you that in real life I'd rather use different tooling, but in an exam environment I don't have that option.

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes does not store more than what is necessary for it to operate and most of the time that is just the desired state because kubernetes is not a version control system.

This is preciously why you need to have a version control system coupled with tools like helm or kustomize where you store the deployment yamls and apply them to the cluster with a new version of the software. This helps in going back in history to dig out details when things break.

Answer (score 1):

You can record the last executed command that changed the deployment with --record option. When using --record you would see the last executed command executed(change-cause) to the deployment metadata.annotations. You will not see this in your local yaml file but when you try to export the deployment as yaml then you will notice the change.

--record option like below

```
kubectl create deployment <deployment name> --image=<someimage> > testdelpoyment.yaml

kubectl create -f testdeployment.yaml --record

or

kubectl set image deployment/<deploymentname> imagename=newimagename:newversion --record
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also get some additional details by passing the `--revision` flag:

```
kubectl rollout history deployment mydep --revision=26
```

Or even `diff` two such revisions in `bash`:

```
diff <(kubectl rollout history deployment mydep --revision=26) \
     <(kubectl rollout history deployment mydep --revision=25)
```